# How to increase Socket Timeout period in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, sdk, socket-timeout-exception, network-connection, razorpay-andoid-sdk

I currently have a slow internet connection and need to download the Android SDK, but I am getting an error "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out".

Is there a way to increase the timeout period to allow for the download to complete?